# I can't access my FTP Server from outside of my network

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ftp

I have set up the FTP Server with a static IP which I can easily use to access it within my network on any other devices. I also have opened port 21 and 20 which has also allowed me to use my external IP to open the FTP Server.

Even so, it still can only be accessed within the network it's on. I have tried turning the firewall on the FTP Server off entirely but that makes no change. If I turn the routers firewall off, I can't access the FTP Server even from within the network. What should I try to do? I just want to access it externally.

I use mobile data on my phone to check externally if it works, though I have also checked on a different computer on a different network and different ISP.

Comment: Passive FTP uses a dynamic port range for incoming data connections. Port 20 is really a thing of the past. Why not use SFTP? It requires only one port.

Comment: You say you assigned it a static IP, so is this a public or private IP address you assigned it? Whatever router/modem pushes the traffic from the outside world to the FTP server, you may need to define port forwarding rules or NAT rules to point to the private IP address of the FTP server. Since you say it connects on the inside and you mention port 21 and port 20, then it sounds like you have your FTP server setup with active connections explicitly which is perfectly fine regardless of what anyone says if that's what you need and want, then use it. You likely have a traffic routing problem.

Comment: You might clarify what FTP server/service you are using and how you have it configured perhaps too otherwise you are going to get suggestions such as use SFTP, use PASV, etc. If ACTIVE insecure plain FTP is a requirement, then you need to state that; otherwise, people are going to tell you to change your configuration to make it something easier to define or something more secure or some other reason. State your requirements, state your basic router config, maybe your router model to, and some of that other detail you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you know that FTP is an insecure protocol, right?

Secondly, your ISP may well be blocking both ports 20 and 21, and inbound ftp traffic (deep packet inspection).

You can try getting around this by using non-standard ports.

But you should really use sftp / scp.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server

Comment: If i change the port number it "Refuses to connect"

Comment: Port number on what?  Most routers/firewalls let you forward a different port to the internal port.  What FTP server are you using? What OS?  What router/firewall, make and model?